# Template-specialization for one out of multiple templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

the header `mycomputationclass.h`:

```
#pragma once
template<typename numberType, bool increaseByOne>
class MyComputationClass
{
   numberType a = 1;
   numberType b = 2;
   numberType compute();
};

#include mycomputationclass.hpp
```

the header implementation file `mycomputationclass.hpp`:

```
#pragma once
#include mycomputationclass.h

template<typename numberType, bool increaseByOne>
numberType MyComputationClass<numberType, increaseByOne>::compute()
{
   return a + b;
}
template<typename numberType>
numberType MyComputationClass<numberType, true>::compute()
{
   return a + b + static_cast<numberType>(1);
}
```

the error:

```
 error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class MyComputationClass<numberType, true>’
 numberType MyComputationClass<numberType, true>::compute()
                                                          ^
```

All topics related to specialisation I find are using only one template. Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Now, your problem doesn't stem from the above, but nevertheless you should strongly consider if you indeed want to implement the template in the cpp file. I suspect you do not.

Anyway the problem you are asking about is that you are trying to define a method of a specialized class template which you haven't specialized.

There are a couple of options here.

- You can specialize the class template, repeating the whole body

  ```
  template<typename numberType>
  class MyComputationClass<numberType, true>
  {
     numberType a = 1;
     numberType b = 2;
     numberType compute();
  };
  ```
- You can create a base class template with all the common code and have derived classes templates with only the parts you need to specialize
- In C++17 you can use `if constexpr`:

  ```
  template<typename numberType, bool increaseByOne>
  numberType MyComputationClass<numberType, increaseByOne>::compute()
  {
      if constexpr (increateByOne)
          return a + b + 1;
      else
          return a + b;
  }
  ```
- In C++20 you can use the requires clause:

  ```
  template<typename numberType, bool increaseByOne>
  class MyComputationClass
  {
     numberType a = 1;
     numberType b = 2;
     numberType compute() requires increaseByOne
     {
         return a + b + 1;
     };
      numberType compute() requires (!increaseByOne)
     {
         return a + b;
     };
  };
  ```
- In old C++ in your case you can use simple if. Since `increaseByOne` is known at compile time the compiler will optimize it as if it were `if constexpr`. The only problem you would have is if you returned different types on each branch or have some code that is invalid on one of the branches. So simple `if` is a solution here:

  ```
  template<typename numberType, bool increaseByOne>
  numberType MyComputationClass<numberType, increaseByOne>::compute()
  {
      if (increateByOne)
          return a + b + 1;
      else
          return a + b;
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I was aware of the if constexpr, but my framework binds me to c++11 unfortunately. In fact I also messed up my question, I put correctly in an implementation header hpp. Corrected this in the question. 
I fear repeating the body or base class is both not so nice for my code, so I assume I will fall back kicking out the template bool again and just make it a member. Pay some computation overhead with normal if.
Thanks a lot still, your answer is nice and clear, prevented me from trial and error. And it might help others. Bye

Comment: accepted your answer as well, as my question is gone, but not my problem unfortunately :)

Comment: @JanHackenberg there would be no computation overhead. I've edited the answer.

Comment: This is good to know, yesterday I made the flag a simply member and had it work at least.

I might reintroduce the templated bool stuff then again. I call this code few billion times during optimization routine, and to optimize the if away might be a tiny bit runtime improvement. Thank you so much. I edited your answer, as your code fragment for old c++ still contained if const expression.